# Como instalar xampp con php 7.4 y driver de SQL Server PDO_SQLSRV en linux

Tags: php, linux, pdo

en esta ocasión me encuentro con un problema a la hora de instalar el xampp pues necesito que me corra con los driver de PDO_SQLSRV para la conexión a base de datos con SQL SERVER, soy nuevo con el manejo de distribuciones linux, en estos momentos trabajo con Linux Mint 20

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado / intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes?

Comment: En Linux se debe instalar cada componente por separado. ¿Sabes usar la terminal?

Comment: Puedes descarar el paquete para linux desde la pagina oficial https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html

Comment: @Triby pues apenas estoy empezando en este mundo, ya has realizado ese proceso que me puedas explicarlo

Comment: @A.Cedano pues en todo lo que he investigado no he encontrado nada en concreto, o bueno quizá mucha información confusa.

Comment: Como bien dice @Triby, en Linux se suele instalar cada componente por separado, por lo general desde la Terminal. [Aquí tienes un tutorial para instalar Xampp](https://www.neoguias.com/instalar-xampp-linux-mint/). Luego, busca algún tutorial para instalar los controladores de PDO, por lo general basta con ejecutar un comando en la Terminal que te instalará los archivos y quizá debas configurar algo en `php.ini` para activar esos controladores.